# Regular Expression to exclude CRLF from a line in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression that would extract data and put into three different group: begin, CustomerNo and end.

```
^(?<begin>(.*?[|]){14})(?<CustomerNo>.*?)(?<end>[|].*)*$
```

This is working, except that the "end" group would contain CrLf character at the end. Is there a way to not to include CrLf character at the end of each line with the regular expression above?

Comment: Do you use any modifiers ? What language do you use? repeating a capuring group is a little strange.

Comment: i'm using c#; however the task is not to use c# to remove any CrLf. My work, i can modify the code to remove CrLf, but it will take sometimes to deploy to production due to reviewing, and other constraints. Therefore, using regular expression to exclude CrLf char would be the fast solution now. However, I could not figure how to exclude it.

Comment: is the string processed line by line (in other words: do you use the multiline mode?)

Comment: RegexOptions is set to Multiline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@"^(?<begin>(.*?[|]){14})(?<CustomerNo>.*?)(?<end>[|][^\r\n]*)"
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I tried this before, but i made a mistake instead of what you have, i used: @"^(?<begin>(.*?[|]){14})(?<CustomerNo>.*?)(?<end>[|]^[\r\n]*)"

Comment: @Andy: give this a try: `@"^(?<begin>(?>[^|]*[|]){14})(?<CustomerNo>[^|]*)(?<end>[|][^\r\n]*)"`  if it works, it will be a faster pattern.